# Mass Storage with Arduino Uno and LUFA

Tags: arduino-uno

guys ! I want to implement the mass storage example from the LUFA Library to my Arduino Uno, but I do not know where to start. Has anybody done this successfully and could give me a few pieces of advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start by taking the Uno and putting it aside, and picking up an AVR-based Arduino that has native USB device support such as a Leonardo or Esplora. You can then use the build scripts that come with LUFA to build the code for your device.